# validate the star rating using jquery validation engine master

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to Validate star rating using jquery validation engine master. I Have tried that But It doesn't seem to work. Can any one please help me on this??

```
 <input class="star required" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="1" title="Worst"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="2" title="Bad"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="3" title="OK"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="4" title="Good"/>
    <input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="5" title="Best"/> 

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will workout, just check you code in form and its form id should be "formID"

```
<input class="star validate[required,] " type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="1" title="Worst"/>
<input class="star validate[required,] " type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="2" title="Bad"/>
<input class="star validate[required,]" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="3" title="OK"/>
<input class="star validate[required,] " type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="4" title="Good"/>
<input class="star validate[required,] " type="radio" name="test-1-rating-4" value="5" title="Best"/>
```